# Find nested elements on instagram with selenium - python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, bots, instagram

I wrote a Python web script, with selenium, and I want to find a specific element, but I was not successful. Web page codes:

```
<div class="_2ic5v">
      <button class="wpO6b ZQScA " type="button">
           <div class="QBdPU B58H7">
               <svg aria-label="Like" class="_8-yf5 " color="#8e8e8e" fill="#8e8e8e" height="12" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="12">
                      <path d="M16.792 3.904A4.989 4.989 0 0121.5 9.122c0 3.072-2.652 4.959-5.197 7.222-2.512 2.243-3.865 3.469-4.303 3.752-.477-.309-2.143-1.823-4.303-3.752C5.141 14.072 2.5 12.167 2.5 9.122a4.989 4.989 0 014.708-5.218 4.21 4.21 0 013.675 1.941c.84 1.175.98 1.763 1.12 1.763s.278-.588 1.11-1.766a4.17 4.17 0 013.679-1.938m0-2a6.04 6.04 0 00-4.797 2.127 6.052 6.052 0 00-4.787-2.127A6.985 6.985 0 00.5 9.122c0 3.61 2.55 5.827 5.015 7.97.283.246.569.494.853.747l1.027.918a44.998 44.998 0 003.518 3.018 2 2 0 002.174 0 45.263 45.263 0 003.626-3.115l.922-.824c.293-.26.59-.519.885-.774 2.334-2.025 4.98-4.32 4.98-7.94a6.985 6.985 0 00-6.708-7.218z">
                      </path>
               </svg>
           </div>
           <div class="QBdPU rrUvL">
                  <span class="">
                      <svg aria-label="Like" class="_8-yf5 " color="#262626" fill="#262626" height="12" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="12">
                            <path d="M16.792 3.904A4.989 4.989 0 0121.5 9.122c0 3.072-2.652 4.959-5.197 7.222-2.512 2.243-3.865 3.469-4.303 3.752-.477-.309-2.143-1.823-4.303-3.752C5.141 14.072 2.5 12.167 2.5 9.122a4.989 4.989 0 014.708-5.218 4.21 4.21 0 013.675 1.941c.84 1.175.98 1.763 1.12 1.763s.278-.588 1.11-1.766a4.17 4.17 0 013.679-1.938m0-2a6.04 6.04 0 00-4.797 2.127 6.052 6.052 0 00-4.787-2.127A6.985 6.985 0 00.5 9.122c0 3.61 2.55 5.827 5.015 7.97.283.246.569.494.853.747l1.027.918a44.998 44.998 0 003.518 3.018 2 2 0 002.174 0 45.263 45.263 0 003.626-3.115l.922-.824c.293-.26.59-.519.885-.774 2.334-2.025 4.98-4.32 4.98-7.94a6.985 6.985 0 00-6.708-7.218z">
                            </path>
                      </svg>
                  </span>
           </div>
       </button>
</div>
```

and code image:
[image]

I want to get the **svg: aria-label** element and the **Like** value, and my code is:

```
driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//div[@class="_2ic5v"]/*[name()="svg"][@aria-label="Like"]')
```

But with this code, I can not get any element and result, Thanks for helping.

Comment: Let me add one more point: I tried again to get the elements through the following code: `driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//div[@class="_2ic5v"]/div[@class="QBdPU rrUvL"]/*[name()="svg"][@aria-label="Like"]'` I want to receive the svg element, and I have a lot of svg element in web page, so I use `find_elements` but I have not reached a conclusion yet.

Comment: Can you pass url and i will try to help you.